# Cap values within an AVERAGEIF() statement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to find an average of the range J2:J214

The range is full of percentages, many of which are 0 and I don't want 0's to be incorporated into the average.  Problem,  a few of these numbers are over 100% which distorts the average.  I want a function that will cap the inputs to the average at 100%.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
=AVERAGEIF(J2:J214,"<>0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Averageifs()`:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(J2:J214, J2:J214, ">0", J2:J214, "<=1")
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll accept this as answered in 10 minutes